# why am i getting a bool returned instead of sql variable

Tags: mysql, php, sql

i have stored ip addresses in a table and am trying to print them out on my webpage
  http://freegifts.virtualworker.online/verify.php

but i get this error

> Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in /homepages/31/d784186148/htdocs/clickandbuilds/GiveawaysandFreebiesbyJoel/verify.php on line 22

the weird thing is if i use my vistors table instead of the one i need it works.

heres my code

```
<?php
include_once 'dbh.inc.php';


?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <?php
      //Here is an example where we use the connection to take data from our database, and show it in the browser


      //Here we mix PHP and SQL in order to have a statement ready that we can refer to later on

      //Here we "query" the SQL statement in the database using our connection variable
        $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM postback");
      //Here we get the number of results the query returned from the database
        $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    echo "1";
      //We then check if we had atleast 1 result from the database
        if ($resultCheck > 0) { echo  $resultCheck;
        //If we had a result, then we use a while loop to spit out our rows of data, one by one
        //At the same time we also assign the database data to a variable named $row
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
          //We can spit out the data by refering to our database column names
                echo $row['ufirst'] . "<br>";
            }
        }
    else echo "3";
    ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

the error is at  `$resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);`

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php):

> Returns FALSE on failure. For successful SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE or EXPLAIN queries mysqli_query() will return a mysqli_result object. For other successful queries mysqli_query() will return TRUE.

You have to test the return value before any operation and display the error code.

```
        if (!$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM postback")) {
            printf("Error: %s\n", $mysqli->error);
            exit;
        }
```